# How to get Citizen Patrol Badge

Tags: support, flagging, badges

I got two helpful flags already but until now I don't have received the Citizen Patrol Badge. What shall I do? Sorry for this question, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Citizen Patrol badge description](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol) states it is awarded for

> First flagged post.

According to [your flagging summary](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/44376)<sup>*</sup>, you have not flagged any *posts*, only *comments*.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Get to it by clicking on the line with the flag information in the right side of [your activity tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity).</sub>

Comment: I did it. I go there and whats next? http://math.stackexchange.com/users/44376/juniven?tab=topactivity

Comment: @juniven I linked to your flagging summary in the main part of my answer above. To get to it from your activity tab, there should be a box on the right side with "IMPACT" at the top, and below information about "posts edited", "helpful flags" and "votes cast". Click on "helpful flags" line.